# how to resolve memory error in python

Tags: python

```
target.shape = (1,32561)

train.shape = (21706,)

trial.shape = (32561,15)

model.fit(trial[train, :],target[train])


> **MemoryError:**
```

What is the alternative to avoid memory for this code segment.

Comment: What library do you use? What are `target`, `train`, and `shape`?

Comment: How could you possibly think you've provided enough information for anyone to be able to help you?

Comment: There are  5 ways to resolve a memory error, depending on the root of the problem: install more RAM, free the RAM from other processses, make sure the OS allows the process the use all available RAM, use less RAM and fix a possible memory leak. Your far less than minimal example does not allow to identify the cause of the memory error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import gc` and run `gc.collect()` wherever you feel there could be a possible memory leak.

You can also use `del <variable-1>,..., <variable-n>` to free the memory of variables that you will not be using.

Comment: suggestion helped in searching for possibilities of freeing memory or bypassing memory while running the code.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to solve memory errors was to use `numpy.memmap` which creates a memory-map to an array stored in a binaryfile on disk.
These Memory mapped files are used for accessing small segments of large files on disk, without reading the entire file into memory, which mayn't require to add more RAM(possibly).